# How to format a column to 2 decimal places in sql

Tags: sql

Need to format column "Layers Ordered" to 2 decimal places. I have messed with the round function but have not been able to pull data with a decimal, only whole numbers. Any ideas how I can format the select statement to return 2 decimals for column "Layers Ordered"?

```
[select distinct shipment.ship_id "Shipment",
        ord_line.ordnum "Order",
        ord_line.ordlin "Order Line",
        ord_line.prtnum "Item",
        (ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas) "Cases Ordered",
        (prtftp_view.untlay / prtftp_view.untcas) "Cases Per Layer",
        ((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas) / (prtftp_view.untlay / prtftp_view.untcas)) "Layers Ordered",
        case when ord_line.prtnum in (select distinct prtnum
                                        from inventory_view
                                       where inventory_view.stoloc like 'LP%A') then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end "Item Slotted Layer"
   from car_move
   join shipment
     on shipment.aesitn = car_move.host_ext_id
   join ord_line
     on ord_line.rt_adr_id = shipment.rt_adr_id
   join prtftp_view
     on prtftp_view.prtnum = ord_line.prtnum
  where car_move.car_move_id in ('LD00030697', 'LD00030627', 'LD00030629')
    and prtftp_view.ftpcod not like '%SAP'
    and prtftp_view.wh_id = 'US_5035'
  order by shipment.ship_id,
        ord_line.ordnum,
        ord_line.ordlin]
```

[image: SQL]

Comment: Rounding is different from formatting. Rounding a number means to change it internally to remove decimal places (keeping a numeric result), while formatting means to produce a visual string representation of it with a specific format (producing a text result). **Which one do you want?**

Comment: format to "1.23" as an example @TheImpaler

Comment: You want formatting. What's the database? Formatting functions vary per database.

Comment: ((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas) / (prtftp_view.untlay / prtftp_view.untcas)) "Layers Ordered"

Database is on secured network. But this is line needing to be formatted as above

Comment: What's the database? -> Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: to_char((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas) / (prtftp_view.untlay / prtftp_view.untcas), 99.99) "Layers Ordered",

Believe I got it. This seemed to have done the trick. Database is lextedit, apologies.

Comment: Yep, that's formatting. And that's looks like Oracle database.

Comment: Most likely, just know application is LextEdit. Thanks for your help sir!

Comment: Hint: Next time, try a minimal example.